# I could fetch the data in winjs of type blob and text. now i want to fetch the json type. and that json data i have to convert it to XML form

Tags: javascript, winjs

```
  <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="xhrDiv"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    //to fetch text type

    WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://www.sportskeeda.com/2013/01/15/fluminense-in-talks-with-       riquelme/", responseType: "text" })
   .done(
     function (request) {
     var text = request.responseText;
     var subText = text.substring(text.indexOf("Brazilian"), text.indexOf("Xinhua.") + 9);
     xhrDiv.innerHTML = subText;
     });

     // to fetch blob type

     WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://www.microsoft.com/windows/Framework/images/win_logo.png",    responseType: "blob" })
     .done(
     function (request) {
     var imageBlob = URL.createObjectURL(request.response);
     var imageTag = xhrDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("image"));
     imageTag.src = imageBlob;
     });

    </script>
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question, I don't quite understand what you are saying you want to do? You have some data and you want to convert it to XML?

Comment: You'll need to construct the XML document from the JSON you've requested. Is this for some XML to upload somewhere?

Comment: i extracted data from a website using XML now i want to push the same data to an windows 8 app. how to go?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009720/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-pull-a-local-xml-file-and-apply-it-to-the-windows-8/14014338#14014338

Comment: I'm sorry, but you really need to be a lot more specific than "it's not working". Do you mean: A) the data from the service never completes b) you can't parse the XML when you try to manipulate it's DOM c) It's got nothing to do with the actual problem you're trying to solve?